# Is there any code which can segregate the different data types to different arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, types

```
horse.dtypes

surgery                   object
age                       object
hospital_number            int64
rectal_temp              float64
pulse                    float64
respiratory_rate         float64
temp_of_extremities       object
peripheral_pulse          object
mucous_membrane           object
capillary_refill_time     object
pain                      object
peristalsis               object
abdominal_distention      object
nasogastric_tube          object
nasogastric_reflux        object
nasogastric_reflux_ph    float64
rectal_exam_feces         object
abdomen                   object
packed_cell_volume       float64
total_protein            float64
abdomo_appearance         object
abdomo_protein           float64
surgical_lesion           object
lesion_1                   int64
lesion_2                   int64
lesion_3                   int64
cp_data                   object
dtype: object
```

**I want to segregate those above data types by creating a new variable**

For e.g:

```
object_vars = ['surgery', 'age','temp_of_extremities', 'peripheral_pulse',
   'mucous_membrane', 'capillary_refill_time', 'pain', 'peristalsis',
   'abdominal_distention', 'nasogastric_tube', 'nasogastric_reflux', 'rectal_exam_feces', 'abdomen','abdomo_appearance','surgical_lesion','cp_data']
```

**Is there any code which can smooth down the process and categorize them to different variables**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but the following code would give the result you gave as an example, i.e. a list of all column names of the same data type:

```py
import pandas as pd

# create bogus data
o1 = object()
o2 = object()
i1 = 2
f1 = 5.

horse = pd.DataFrame([[o1,i1,f1,o2]],
                     columns = ("surgery", "lesion_1","pulse","pain"))

# list all present data_types
dtypes = horse.dtypes.unique()

# build dict with datatype name as key
data_by_type = {str(dtype): horse.loc[:,horse.dtypes==dtype].columns.to_list() for dtype in dtypes}
```

```
print(data_by_type["object"])
['surgery', 'pain']
```